# Giving someone access to an addon website on my server

Tags: hosting

I need to give someone access to a website I made for a friend but only want them to have access to the addon domain folder. Is this possible (with JustHost)?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In case anyone was wondering, in the control panel on JustHost there is an FTP Accounts section where you can give access to certain addon domains such as public_html/domainname.com with its own login.